# Host to mount container directory to the host?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume

I build a image of my web project with all my dependencies in the image at `/app`. When running the container it's start blazing fast and I'm able to access the application instantly.

However I build all the thing directly in the Dockerfile so the host has nothing except the Dockerfile.

So I try to retrieve the project files like so `docker run -v $(pwd):/app image_name` but it seems the folder is overrided  because when trying to serve the public folder it can't be found anymore. By just exclude the volume option it's start well.

Am I right when I'm thinking it override my container folder?

Why did this works for the GitLab Project? (https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#prerequisites)

They got all the project in the container, and mount it on the host.

```
sudo docker run --detach \
    --hostname gitlab.example.com \
    --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --restart always \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

For named volumes, the image contents are copied from the image to the named volumes upon volume creation. This named volume will have the contents of `/bin` copied to the volume:

```
docker run -ti -v busyboxbin:/bin busybox sh
```

Bind mounted directories are mounted in place and override any image contents. So this example would fail (unless you already had a copy of the files in `/tmp/empty`)

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/empty:/bin busybox sh
```

The gitlab container will populate the bind mounted volume contents after the image was started. The logs are easy to add what's there. The data directory may need to be initialised by the app. The image probably comes with pre canned config to populate and run with if no files exist.